# Running out of memory when building a language model in Fast.ai 1.0

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, out-of-memory, language-model, fast-ai

I'm dealing with a rather large text dataset (5.4 million short texts) and I'm trying to perform sentiment analysis con them on 16GB of ram.

I keep running out of memory whenever I try to build the language model:

```
data_lm = text_data_from_csv(DATASET_PATH, data_func=lm_data, chunksize=4000)
# Out of memory
data_clas = text_data_from_csv(DATASET_PATH, data_func=classifier_data, vocab=data_lm.train_ds.vocab, chunksize=500)
```

I've played around with the chunksize but the memory usage seems to keep rising over time and eventually results in a memory error.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: do you mind sharing the whole notebook on github and posting the link here?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `chunksize` below 100 and try to use `GPU`
refer to this link to find more information [fastai](https://docs.fast.ai/text.data.html#TextDataBunch.from_csv)